# Code to separate rows of data on a sheet: A Solution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Situation: Wife is principal of school. Lesson plans are submitted by teachers (via variant of Google Form) to folder on her Google Drive. A  Google Sheet is simultaneously populated with Teacher name, Monday of submission week (the "key"), and File Uploaded. If you right-click the File name, select Open, it appears. So you have 10 entries for August 6, 13, 20, 27 in consecutive rows. To separate submissions by Monday of submission week, the following code works:

```
function RowInsert() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  var lr = ss.getLastRow() 
  var c = 0;
  var data = ss.getRange(1, 1, lr, 1).getValues() 
  for (r = 1; r < (data.length) + c; r++) {   
    if ((ss.getRange(r, 1).getValue() !== "" ) && 
        (ss.getRange(r+1, 1).getValue() !== "" )) { 
      if (ss.getRange(r, 1).getValue() !== ss.getRange(r+1, 1).getValue() && 
          ss.getRange(r, 1).getValue() !== "" ) {
        ss.insertRowBefore(r+1);  
        c = c + 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you use this code, obviously make sure correct column is referenced. Hope this helps someone. I am a VBA programmer new to Google script, thanks to Mr. Nelson for helping me get started. I also wrote a function to delete empty rows. As I developed/tested code, was getting tired of physically deleting empty rows to retest. I can provide this code as well. Thanks to all.

Comment: There is no question?

Comment: I am new to Google Script and this forum. I was simply trying to help others who may have come across this situation. Sorry that I posted a solution rather than question, my bad.

Comment: @ronald, it's ok to post your solution. You may edit the question to make it look like a question and answer it.

Comment: @ronald also please make indents in your code to make it more readable.

Comment: @ronald Use the "Post your answer" below to answer your own question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no question has been presented (please rewrite as a Q&A and we can get it reopened).